# How do I get URL parameters without a router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to access my react with `localhost:3000/?x=10&y=10`

But the URL object is always empty

```
const search = window.location.search;
const params = new URLSearchParams(search);

console.log(params);

URLSearchParams {  }
```

I don't need any router or something. How do I access x and y from url in react?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data is in there, you just need to grab it!

[The `URLSearchParams` object has a defined api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) with methods that you need to call.

```js
const search = '?x=10&y=10' // value of window.location.search
const params = new URLSearchParams(search);

console.log(params.get('x'));
for (const [key, value] of params) {
  console.log(key, 'is', value);
}
```